# What should I know about tractate Bava Kamma as this part of daf yomi approaches?

Tags: torah-study, bava-kamma

What should I know about tractate Bava Kamma as this part of daf yomi approaches? Any tips to keep in mind while studying it? It's the start of a new Seder of Talmud so it may have a different manner of teaching that I might be unaware of.

Comment: Is this Too Broad?

Comment: If you have any suggestions, I'd be happy to modify the question.

Comment: Suggestion - explain your last sentence. We don't know your knowledge level or your concerns to discern what you really need.

Comment: I would be very happy to answer you @CoolGuy,  but in this MY setting it is very difficult.  For a start there are a lot of pesukim involved. It is not good to learn such types of g'moros.  For another one has to realise we are talking about someone whose "articles" damage others.  The torah has a lot of leniency  because of this and that is basically what the whole bava kama is about.  One also has to understand the exact case of the g'moro, the meforshim often conflict on this.  It is legal matters of which there are often two sides and one is left deciding which.

Comment: review is important. dont expect to understand such a new world right away

Answer (score 2):

First you can learn most verses concerning BK in parashat Mishpatim, with Rashi. In a second step mishnayot with Bartenura. A second time parasha with Rashi and Mishnayot with Bartenura and Ykar Tosfot Yom Tov. In BK, specially for the 7nt chapter the Gemara contain a lot of drashot. If you know the verses it will be easier.

Comment: The second time through should probably be with Mechilta instead of Rashi and Tosefta instead of Mishna

Comment: @DoubleAA it is very chalanging